# Node API update not working

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman

I am testing an API by trying to update an array with a file name using Postman.
The array is empty when I query it with mongo.
The  user model which has an image array:

```
var UserSchema   = new Schema({
    name: String,
    email: { type: String, required: true, validate: [validate.email, 'invalid email address'],
    index: { unique: true }},
    password: { type: String, required: true, select: false },
    images: [{ name: String }]
});
```

The apiRouter express router:

```
apiRouter.put('/images/:user_id/:file_name', function(req, res){

        User.findById(req.params.user_id, function(err, user) {     
                //console.log(req.params.user_id);
                //console.log(req.params.file_name);
                user_id = req.params.user_id;
                file_name = req.params.file_name;

                user.update({$addToSet:{'images': file_name}});

                user.save(function(err) {
                    if (err) return res.send(err);
                        res.json({ message: 'User updated!' });
                });
        });
    });
```

Postman:

```
PUT  http://localhost:3000/api/images/5626fd2903c49d6231518c9/imageA
```

and mongo db.find():

```
"images" : [ ]
```

file_name holds the correct "imageA" value but as you can see the images array is empty.

Comment: you mean to say that image name not inserting in mongodb right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing this all wrong. Updates with operators like [`$addToSet`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/) are meant to be atomic, which means they make the change directly on the database and are then done with it.

So calls like [`.update()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) require both a query component for matching the document(s) and an "update" component to modify the matched document(s):

```
apiRouter.put('/images/:user_id/:file_name', function(req, res) {

    User.update(
        { "_id": req.params.user_id },
        { "$addToSet": {"images": req.params.file_name } },
        function(err,numAffected) { 
            if (err) { 
                return res.send(err);
            } else if ( numAffected == 0 ) {
                res.json({ "message": "Not found" })
            } else {
                res.json({ "message": "User updated!" });
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Else use [`.findByIdAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) to return the modified document:

```
apiRouter.put('/images/:user_id/:file_name', function(req, res) {

    User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.user_id,
        { "$addToSet": {"images": req.params.file_name } },
        { "new": true },
        function(err,user) { 
            if (err) { 
                return res.send(err);
            } else if ( !user ) {
                res.json({ "message": "Not found" })
            } else {
                res.json(user);
            }
        }
    );
});
```

Also noting that it is not an `err` if no document is matched to perform the update, but rather the affected document(s) will be `0` or in the latter function case there will be no document returned.

You only use methods like `.save()` when you have retrieved the document and have modified content in regular code and not database methods. It's not a good practice to "retrieve/modify/save" as other operations can likely update the document in the database in between those actions occuring, leaving you with overwritten information and an inconsistent state.

Comment: Thank you very much for the wealth of information given here. It is very much appreciated.